# Can someone explain why this conditional jump is not taken?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86

Please check this screenshot of my x32dbg:
[image]

```
00408951 | 3D E8030000              | cmp eax,3E8                             |
00408956 | 7F 3A                    | jg debugme.408992                       |
```

Since `eax` (8349294D) is greater then 0x3E8, why that `jg` is not taken?
And no, I didn't change the flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JG` is jump if *signed greater than*, or in other words, ZF=0 and SF=OF.

8349294D is negative and 0x3E8 is positive, so ZF=0 but SF=1 and OF=0 so SF!=OF, as visible in your flags panel (underlined). The value of CF does not matter to `JG`.

Answer (score 3):

`jg` is a for a signed comparison.  As a signed 32 bit number, EAX is negative.

You should use `ja` (for above), which is unsigned comparison.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!